# Alternative to public hot water bath in Japan for a tattooed person

Tags: japan

I'm going to Japan in a of couple months.

I've got 80% of my back tattooed and I would really like to try the experience of a public bath in Japan.

Many people have been telling me that it is not allowed for people who have tattoos.

My question is. What would be an alternative for a public bath for me?

Is there a private bath, a place where I can pay for the same experience e don't be banned?

Comment: You may be interested in [I have a tattoo. Can I visit a public swimming pool in Japan?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3631/101)

Comment: I have interested in alternatives to public swimming pool.

Comment: Yes, that's why I didn't provide it as an answer, just as a read.  Hopefully someone with more experience can provide you with an answer soon. Good luck!

Comment: There are many Tatoo-OK public baths in Japan, especially where many yakuza live. One of such areas is Yoyogi area in Tokyo. It would be harder with onsen though.

Comment: [3 Hot Spring Facilities to Enjoy the Japanese Public Bathing Culture Even if You Have Tattoos!](http://jpninfo.com/52675)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are lots of public baths in Japan that are free, unattended and thus open to everybody.  Here are a few in [Yagen Valley](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Yagen_Valley), Aomori, built right next to a river:

[image]
[image]

And I shared the first of those with some gentlemen with full-back tattoos, done in a traditional style instantly recognizable to any Japanese.

Now Yagen's about as far from it all as it gets in Japan, but there are *lots* of these in rural areas if you look, some of them quite famous ([Jigokudani](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Yamanouchi) of monkey fame, [Kawayu Onsen](http://www.tb-kumano.jp/en/onsen/kawayu/), etc).

And not all professionally run onsen are anti-tattoo, here's a good (Japanese-only) listing of [tattoo-friendly onsen in Hokkaido](http://tattooworks.net/t_spa.html).  Interestingly, quite a few say things like "OK as long as it's not full-back" or even "Fashion tattoos are OK, but *irezumi* [Japanese traditional tattoos] are not"!

Answer (score 17):

Many hotels and ryokan have a [family bath](http://japantraveleronline.com/theme/G20622/), that is, a bathing facility that can be reserved for private use by families or other groups. This can range from a simple bathroom with a large tub available for free to guests of the hotel up to an luxurious outdoor onsen at $50 per hour.

Of course, you would be alone there unless you bring along friends. I can't tell from your question, but if by "experience of a public bath in Japan" you mean that you want to mingle with regular Japanese guests, you're probably out of luck; the ban on tattoos is not specific to publically owned facilities; private operators are just as (if not even more) likely to have it.

There are baths that are run by or are friendly to the yakuza and also open to the public; those will allow you to enter with tattoos.

Comment: I'm a black belt of Jiu Jitsu, does it make any difference to my admission ? (: just a joke :)

Answer (score 14):

There are a variety of grades of public bath in Japan, reflected in the facilities and the pricing.

- *onsen* are resort-class baths.
- *tennen onsen* ("natural onsen") are anything but natural; they're man made onsen constructed by boring down into the ground until you hit geothermally heated water, which is then treated with chemicals to resemble the mineral composition of onsen water.
- *super sento* is just plain water, but with a variety of baths, usually a sauna, etc.
- *sento* is the cheap neighbourhood bathhouse. It may only have two or three baths, and you take your own soap and shampoo.

Super sentos and up normally prohibit tattoos. Every sento I have been in has had at least one person with tattoos, and sometimes the saunas are obviously being used for business meetings by people with punch perms who describe their jobs as "a little bit of this and that." Those places are more interesting anyway.

Comment: The bit about "tennen onsen" is misleading.  *Tennen onsen* is a legal term for an onsen that is geothermally heated and contain at least one approved mineral naturally; a plain old *onsen* does not meet one or both criteria, and is "lower" on the scale.   Note that it's fairly common for *tennen onsen* to only use some natural heating (instead of all) and adjust the mineral mix, but being "all-natural" is a big plus for marketing.

Comment: Out of curiosity - if your tattoo(s) are relatively small is it possible to cover them with a skin-colored bandage and be allowed to enter?

Answer (score 2):

Now I don't speak any Japanese but [this Japan site with tips on Onsen bathing](http://wanderweib.de/tipps-onsen-in-japan-besuchen/) (in German) includes a link to a [site with a directory of tattoo-friendly spas/baths/onsen](http://tattoo-spot.jp/tattoo/spa/). Since it is in Japanese only and I know next to nothing about that I can't judge for its content, but it does seem very legit.